# Relation between strong and weak $L_{p}$-norms

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I would like to show that for $p>0$ and any $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$,we have
\begin{equation}
 \| x \|_{p} \leq Ln(eN )^{1/p} \|x \|_{p, \infty}.
\end{equation}
I know how to show that $\| x\|_{p, \infty} \leq \| x\|_{p}$ using nonincreasing rearrangement of $\textbf{x}$, but I am not sure how to show the above inequality. Do you have any suggestions/hints on getting this proof done? Or could you point me to useful inequalities which involve $ Ln(eN )$?